# Is it possible to cast a DECIMAL to DOUBLE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, casting, double, decimal

I know all the numerical implications, that is, the possible rounding issues inherent to floating point formats, but in my case I have `DECIMAL` columns in `MySQL` that I want to convert to `DOUBLE` straight in the `MySQL` query rather than down stream.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Did you try it? `CAST (fldName as DOUBLE)`? [I don't have access to MySQL at the moment to check]. If you are using it in application it will probably be presented to it as double anyway. Why do you want to do it? Double is just more imprecise Decimal.

Comment: `CAST` can't cast to `DOUBLE` as pointed out in the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast). And in this case I only use `DECIMAL` as an efficient intermediary way of storing data. The code using the data from the queries are all in floating point format.

Comment: I fail to see your point/problem/reason. Your code uses floating point (not many programming languages have built-in decimal type), yours obviously does not. *But** if you want to use and handle it in SQL as double/float why **don't** you? Store it as double, then you will **NOT** need to cast it.  (It never occurred to me to check limitations on `CAST`) **And** if you **DO know** that you can't CAST to DOUBLE, **why are you asking** this question???

Comment: Like I said in my comment above, I am using `DECIMAL` in the database to save space.

Comment: And I am interested if any `MySQL` guru would happen to know if this is possible, hence my question.

Comment: Still does **NOT** make any sense to me - calculate in double/float then store in decimal to save space (??? - it is **NOT** 1980s) risking loss of precision **EVERY** time you fetch **AND** store the values. **WHY**?

Comment: Whoaaaa... you're using `DECIMAL` to save space? How much space are you saving? `DECIMAL` packs 9 base-10 digits into 4 bytes, with the integer and fractional parts counted separately. In order to save any meaningful amount of storage (I guess these days we'd be talking GiBs?), your table would have to contain *billions* of rows. Does it? I agree with @GermannArlington: it sounds like you want `DOUBLE` (or perhaps `FLOAT`?) all the way through. If one wanted `DECIMAL` for its precision (as is usually the case), one would want to avoid the loss of such precision in casting to `DOUBLE`.

Comment: I am using combinations of `SMALLINT` and `MEDIUMINT` which are shifted according to fit the decimal places I want. In my case my numbers need more precision than scale. This way I managed to cut the size of the database in half (compared to using `DOUBLE`). The reason for the `DECIMAL` is that any non `INT` operation on an `INT` returns a `DECIMAL`.

Answer (score 13):

`SELECT my_decimal_field + 0E0 FROM my_table`

The following quotes from MySQL manual explain how this works:

[9.1.2 Numeric Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/number-literals.html)

> Number literals include exact-value (integer and DECIMAL) literals and approximate-value (floating-point) literals.
>
> Numbers represented in scientific notation with a mantissa and exponent are approximate-value numbers.

[12.22.3 Expression Handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-expressions.html)

> Handling of a numeric expression depends on what kind of values the expression contains:
>
> - If any approximate values are present, the expression is approximate and is evaluated using floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: Old question, but can someone explain why this converts decimal to double?

Answer (score 2):

Because of the limitations of the built in `CAST` function in MySQL, it is only possible to convert `DECIMAL` to `DOUBLE` with your own user defined cast function.

Sample use case:

`SELECT castDecimalAsDouble(0.000000000000000000100000000000);`

Result: `1e-23`

```html
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `castDecimalAsDouble`(
decimalInput DECIMAL(65,30) ) RETURNS double
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE doubleOutput DOUBLE;

SET doubleOutput = decimalInput;

RETURN doubleOutput;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems not possible to cast it to `DOUBLE` which brings problems if you do calculations and for example want to `ROUND()` a `DECIMAL 12,2` in the third digit. Using `ROUND(foo * bar,2)` will just ignore the additional digits if your `foo` and `bar` are DECIMAL 12,2 fields.

That said you can do something like this to still make it work:

```
ROUND(CAST(foo AS DECIMAL(30,15)*CAST(bar AS DECIMAL(30,15)),2)
```

Answer (score -1):

DECIMAL *may* save space.  For example, `DECIMAL(4,2)` occupies only 2 bytes.  `FLOAT` takes 4; `DOUBLE` takes 8.

As for the original question, simply do:

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY COLUMN c DOUBLE ...;
```

(The "..." should include the other stuff you already had, such as `NOT NULL`.)