# How to convert decimal to float in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    llac.name,
    l.Rate,
    ROUND(llac.loan__Interest_Rate__c, 2) 
FROM cl_import.loan__Loan_Account__c llac 
JOIN decision.loan l
    ON llac.id=l.sf_loan_id
WHERE
    (l.Rate) != llac.loan__Interest_Rate__c;
```

llac.loan__Interest_Rate__c is a decimal and i want to convert it into float.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to cast a DECIMAL to DOUBLE in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742322/is-it-possible-to-cast-a-decimal-to-double-in-mysql)

Comment: What is your conception of float versus decimal in the context of a select statement?  Can you show us your current output along with the output you actually want?

Comment: I have never run into such as issue , but i guess you can take help of the language you are using . convert the value to float then make the query

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade you mysql version to 8.0.17
and use CAST(column AS FLOAT)

ref:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33897199)