# What does +0E0 exactly do when applied to a variable in a MySQL table column?

Tags: mysql, double

While I was searching for a way to convert any value from a random numeric type MySQL column to a double type column I came accross to a solution mentioned in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32991084/1353723). I tested this solution with several numeric types and it seems to work fine. Can anyone explain what this `+ 0E0` exactly do? Is this solution safe for my needs?

Comment: It's the same as `+ 0.0`.

Comment: `+` is just addition and `0E0` is zero times ten raised to the zero power.